# How to check if a string contains a date?

Tags: mysql, regex, vb.net, date

I'm trying to iterate on a `DataSet`, this contain a results of query such as `SELECT * FROM tb 1`, now the first three field contains a date, the format saved in the database table is this:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

but the code return this:

```
yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss
```

in particular this:

```
For z = 1 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1

    Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)(z).ToString())

Next
```

So I need to recognize if the current string have this format: `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss` and parse it into: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` I tough to a `regex` pattern for recognize it, but I'm not an expert of regex. Anyway, if there is another solution I'll glad to see. Note that only the first three value and the last one of the table is date, the other values aren't date but contain integer or other string value.

Comment: Is the db column actually a string or a date?

Comment: Column is a DATETIME, if I don't format correctly the date as I shown I get this value 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: Dates dont have a format (formats are just how we show them to users, or a UI shows it to *you*)...the column in the Datatable ought to be a proper NET DateTime type unless you applied a transform in SQL

Comment: Sure but when I peform the insert usually do this: Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") so I apply a format to date to insert. Now I should apply this format on a value that have this layout: yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss 'cause the db don't recognize this format

Comment: Dates do not have a format.  The MySql data provider knows how to covert a NET DateTime type to a MySql DATETIME you do not have to convert to string.  You can format the **output** or what is shown however you like.  In your code read the DataTable object to a DateTime var then format the output however you like

Comment: @Plutonix you have misunderstood the question. I don't ask how to format the date, I ask how I can recognize a string that have a specific format

Comment: I think there are other issues here but you could just perform a replace of / to - on the string. Can you show us the code you're using to insert into the database? A parameter should handle this type of thing so I'm wondering if you may be concatenating values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates do not have a format.  From MSDN:

> Represents an instant in time, typically expressed as a date and time of day.
>   ...
>   Time values are measured in 100-nanosecond units called ticks, and a particular date is the number of ticks since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 A.D. (C.E.) in the GregorianCalendar calendar...For example, a ticks value of **31241376000000000L** represents the date, Friday, January 01, 0100 12:00:00 midnight.

So, a `DateTime` is just a Big Number.  Representing them as "dd/MM/yyyy" is part of the magic of the `DateTime` type.  Part of the issue is this:

```vb
Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)(z).ToString())
```

Row items are `Object`. It wont act like a `DateTime` type unless/until you get it into a `DateTime` variable.  That print as a `DateTime` simple because the DataTable knows the underlying type; but it will use the default format for your Culture.  This makes it *look like* dates have a built in format (or even that the "format changed" if you tried to set it to something), but you are a human and `635882810022222112L` would not make sense to most of us.

To change the output style, you *first* need to get it into a `DateTime` variable.  *Apparently*, a preliminary step is to determine if an arbitrary column is a Date.  Rather than testing the "format" of the **output**, test the underlying data type. This does assume a proper `DateTime` column in the `DataTable`:

```vb
If ds.Tables(0).Columns(n).DataType = GetType(DateTime) Then
    '...
End If
' Or:
If ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)(z).GetType Is GetType(DateTime) Then
    '...
End If
```

Then to change the display, first get it into a `DateTime` variable:

```vb
Dim dt As DateTime
If ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)(z).GetType Is GetType(DateTime) Then
    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)(z))
    ' cant change "format" but you can change how it displays:
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToLongDateString)
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt"))
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd MMM, yyyy"))
End If
```

An easier way to get and convert to `DateTime` is to use the `Field(Of T)` extension:

```vb
Dim dt = ds.Tables(0).Rows(x).Field(Of DateTime)(y)
```

---

`when I peform the insert usually do this: Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") so I apply a format to date to insert... if I don't format correctly the date as I shown I get this value 0000-00-00 00:00:00`

That doesn't apply a format to a date.  It **converts** the `DateTime` to a string.  While "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" is the correct format to use when passing date data *as a string* to MySql, it is not needed.  The MySQL Data provider knows how to convert a Net `DateTime` var to the data MySql needs/wants and back again -- that's its job.

```vb
' this will work fine
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SomeDate", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = myDateTimeVar
```

The format requirement you read about is the what you need to use in the MySql shell or WorkBench UI because you are entering text/string there...from the keyboard.  It does not mean *code* must convert `DateTime` variables to string in a specific format for storing.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using this

```
              Try
                Dim theDate As DateTime = dr.Item(colName)
                Return theDate
            Catch
                ' do something
            End Try
```

I would be happy to see a better method.

Comment: Nope, I don't want access to the column name but to the string like this (example code) => If ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)(z).ToString().HaveThisFormat == "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" so convert the string into the other format..

Answer (score -1):

Based off of what you seem to be asking a simple replace would do

```
For z = 1 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1

    Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)(z).ToString().Replace("/","-"))

Next
```

if it comes in with / they are changed to - if it comes in with - they remain intact.

Depending on the flexibility you want in this, it may be necessary to TryParse to ensure that the value you're working with is actually a valid datetime.